# Selective repeat buffer size

Tags: networking, protocols, network-protocols

Why in selective repeat algorithm both sending and receiving windows don't need to have the same window size, but the sending and receiving buffers should be the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Window size** actually means that how many packets a sender can send and how many packets a receiver can receive until every packet in the window gets acknowledged and received.

But in case of **selective repeat**, *receiver* don't need to keep track of packets received, because it just have to keep putting them into buffer or into file itself, in sequence. Whereas ***sender*** needs to keep track of window and base for keeping the Acknowledgment track.
So in Selective Repeat if you don't even put a window in receiver side, it will work.

But whereas Sending and Receiving **Buffers** do need to be same because they are going to share similar size and type of data. That's why we need to have same size of Sending and Receiving Buffers.

I hope this will help.
Good Question.